# Convert string parameter output into markdown

Tags: php

So I have the following method where I am outputting a message that gets delivered to `wp_mail()`.

```
$this->send_mail(
    "Test@example.com",
    "Pardot Settings Error",
    "The Pardot integration has trigger a Pardot API error: " . PHP_EOL . "
        Error: " . $decode_response['code'] . " \r\n
        Error Description: " . $decode_response['message'] . "
    "
);

/**
 * Send Mail
 *
 * @param string $to
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $message
 * @return bool
 */
public function send_mail(string $to, string $subject, string $message): bool
{
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    ];
    return wp_mail(
        $to,
        $subject,
        $message,
        $headers
    );
}
```

When I receive the output to the email, it doesn't account for the new lines or any specific markup that gets passed.

```
The Pardot integration has trigger a Pardot API error: Error: 51 Error Description: Invalid parameter: field
```

Is there a way to handle markdown inside a string parameter?

Comment: It's sending HTML mail, you need to use `<br>` for newlines.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that worked! I completely overlooked that.